# how to access docker dashboard in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, docker

I have installed docker in my **ubuntu machine** and it is running in **background as service**. How can I access **docker dashboard** now? Is there any way to access that.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [kitematic](https://kitematic.com), from my POV it is the closest to the Mac or Win "Docker Desktop" tool

you can download latest release [here](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/releases)

Note: they officially don't support ubuntu, but **do** provide release for it... and it works OK on my setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
- docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6
- kitematic v0.17.11

preconditions:

1. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)
2. [Manage Docker as a non-root
   user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)
3. (optional) [Install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems)

Steps to install:

1. download kitematic release zip-file
2. unzip deb package
3. install it

***Extra Note***: after installation of kitematic deb package, I had to restart ubuntu for it to initialize properly... there is probably a way to make it working without restart, but I dint have time to play with it...

Comment: it seems that kitematic is now part of the Docker Toolbox which is now discontinued and you should use instead Docker Desktop which is available only for Windows or a mac... Any work around?

Answer (score 5):

### Edit: Docker Desktop for Linux is now available

You can now install and use Docker Desktop on a Linux OS: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/

---

If you are looking for a graphical tool on linux to interact with your containers, you can use Visual Studio Code with the Docker extension:

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Docker on linux does not have dashboard by default. You can access to docker using Docker CLI - `docker` command. And then if you want to use dashboard, you can install some dashboad that work with docker like [`Portainer`](https://www.portainer.io/).